# how do i link a Fuel SDK client to an account on mc.exacttarget.com?

Tags: fuel-sdk, ruby, fuel

I created an account on code@exacttarget that provides a client id and secret, but i don't get how i can use that to then access an account on mc.exacttarget.com.

I'm trying to use the Fuel SDK (ruby gem) to perform a triggered send that has been defined on the mc.exacttarget.com account.

Here's the relevant code

```
client = FuelSDK::Client.new(client: { 'id': 'my id', 'secret': 'my secret' }
triggered_send = FuelSDK::TriggeredSend.new
triggered_send.authStub = client
triggered_send.props = ["CustomerKey", "Name", "TriggeredSendStatus"]
triggered_send.filter = {'Property' => 'CustomerKey','SimpleOperator' => 'equals','Value' => 'my customer key'}
triggered_send.get
```

what am i missing?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have created a server-to-server app in App Center on Code@ExactTarget, you can get the client ID and client secret by from the app page in App Center. Then, you put the client ID in your code where it says 'my id' and the client secret where it says 'my secret'.

Comment: @hubert ..you can find the instruction here : https://code.exacttarget.com/getting-started/setting-up-your-development-environment.html.... and pls mark lan's as an answer!!